# fields_for with association question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I use association data from within a fields_for?

I've got a has many through relationship between users, schools and schools_users. A user can have multiple schools and a school has multiple users. In schools_users there is a user_role field in addition to the common user_id and school_id.

In the show view I have:

```
<% @school.schools_users.each do |user| %>
<tr><td><%= user.user.first_name %> <%= user.user.last_name %></td><td><%= user.user_role %></td></tr>
<% end %>
```

but I can't figure out how to do the same thing from within the fields_for on the edit page.

```
<%= f.fields_for :schools_users do |f| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= NEED USER NAME HERE %></td>
        <td><%= f.select(:user_role, active_role_options)%></td>
        <td><%= link_to_remove_fields 'Delete', f %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what do you want your form to do?

Comment: I would like the nested model to display the user's first_name, last_name (in plain text, no update) from the User model and the user_role (select menu, update) from the schools_users association.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: You're assigning the block variable of your fields_for to `f`, which is the same `f` your `form_for` uses. You should use a different name, like `user_fields`.

With that:

```
<%= f.fields_for :schools_users do |user_fields| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user_fields.text_field :first_name %></td>
    ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, better naming is a good idea, I'll correct that. My dilema though is that I don't want a text field for the user name, just plain text like the show view. Also, the first_name field is not part of user_fields. Assuming that user_fields just represents what is in schools_users, not users.  Thanks for the help!